# How to pass variable of one function to another function with return type using Scala

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to this Scala programming. Can some one help me how can I read a value from one function and pass to another function?

I have tried below code to work, but getting below error. Please help.

Error: Failed to build request: No attribute named 'a'

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef.*
import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation
import io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef.*
import scala.util.Random

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.io.Source
var a,b : String = ""
def fun1(): (String,String) = {
a = "Test1"
b = "Test2"
return (a,b)

}

def fun2(): {
var c = "Test3"
var d = a+b+c
print(d)
}

  val scen1 = scenario("Test1")
    .exec(fun1()).inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpurl)

  val scen2 = scenario("Test2")
    .exec(fun2()).inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpurl1)

setUp(scen1.andThen(scen2))
```

Comment: Just now edited the description with error what am getting

Comment: The error is coming from a library so you need to give details of the library being used and how you are calling it.  Try to give a minimal example. There is also an error in `fun1` (it is returning a `String` when a `(String, String)` is required) so not sure why that isn't being reported.

Comment: And do not use `var` but `val`

Comment: If you're not familiar with Scala, Gatling has a new Java API. You don't have to learn a new language and a new tool at the same time.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung All my function have been written in Scala only. I have defined 15 function for this I have to change my entire code to java which is not a right decision now. If you know about Scala recumbent please do help.

Comment: using exec(_.set()) am able to call the variable from one function to another function.

Answer (score 0):

Gatling's `exec` doesn't take any arbitrary function. Please read the documentation carefully: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#exec